# Generate html table based on 2x mysql db queries

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to show stuff queried from two tables, but on one html table. Data is shown for the last 30 days, based on which, an html table is being generated.
Currently I'm stuck using two queries and generating two html tables:

```
$query1 = mysqli_query( $con, "SELECT date, stuff* " );
while( $record = mysqli_fetch_array( $query1 ) ){
    echo '<html table generated based on query>';
}

$query2 = mysqli_query( $con, "SELECT date, other stuff*" );
while( $record = mysqli_fetch_array( $query2 ) ){
    echo '<another html table generated based on query2>';
}
```

Is there a possibility to show both queries on one html table instead?

Note that it gets tricky since we have dates on one table which are not necessarily found in the second table or vice-versa.

Thanks for the support guys. So far I'm stuck at this:

```
SELECT * FROM user_visit_logs 
LEFT JOIN surfer_stats ON user_visit_logs.date = surfer_stats.date 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM user_visit_logs 
RIGHT JOIN surfer_stats ON user_visit_logs.date = surfer_stats.date
```

The query completes, but the 2nd table fields are all null:
[image: phpmyadmin screenshot]

Furthermore, it breaks when I add additional clause like:

```
WHERE user_id = '{$_SESSION['user_id']}' ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 30
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible to show them in a single table. See colspan property of td element.

Comment: I don't understand how that's relevant to my issue. Basically I have 5 columns from the first db and another 3 columns from the 2nd db. I can't generate them on the same table as formatting breaks since dates from the two db are not necessarily found in both of them.

Comment: @Ivan - Are you trying to merge rows as well? Or will both of the result sets be completely independent of eachother other than the fact that they'll share a table?

Comment: Results are independent, except for date column.

Comment: Please add an screenshot, regarding some part of your initial tables (table1 & table2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are after `FULL OUTER JOIN` concept:

> The FULL OUTER JOIN keyword returns all rows from the left table (table1) and from the right table (table2)

[image]

In which you may use common dates as a shared row.

So the query will get to simple one:

```
$query = "
    SELECT table1.date, stuff
    FROM table1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 ON table1.date = table2.date
    UNION
    SELECT table2.date, other_stuff
    FROM table1
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN table2
    ON table1.date = table2.date
";
$result = mysqli_query( $con, $query );

while( $record = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) ){
    echo '<html table generated based on query>';
}
```

## Example

This is an schematic diagram of `FULL OUTER JOIN` concept:

[image]

Comment: Mysql does not support full outer join. You need to use union to achive the same.

Comment: @Shadow tnx for notable comment dude!

Comment: Been trying this with no luck: " Column 'date' in field list is ambiguous"

Comment: @Ivan you need to prefix the `date` field with table names. check update in a minute :)

Comment: Alright, the query completes, but the result of the 2nd table is null for all fields.

Comment: I am sure you have some problem with your query. please recheck and try to do it exactly as the given snippet in my answer.

Comment: There is no difference in mysql between left join and left outer join. They are one and the same. Same goes for right join as well.

Comment: Alright so the join worked, however I need to join another column at the same time which holds the clause I need to filter for, column named "user_id"

Comment: @Ivan Please search for `FULL OUTER JOIN with multiple columns` or ask another question, as this is not related to the current question title

Comment: Solved already. Thanks for the help and getting me on the right track. Much appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

After running into quite a few bumps with this one, I finally managed to merge 2 columns from each table and also to use where and sort clauses on them with the following query:

```
( SELECT user_visit_logs.user_id,user_visit_logs.date,unique_hits,non_unique_hits,earned,sites_surfed,earnings FROM user_visit_logs 
LEFT OUTER JOIN surfer_stats ON user_visit_logs.user_id = surfer_stats.user_id AND user_visit_logs.date = surfer_stats.date where user_visit_logs.user_id = 23 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 30 )
UNION 
( SELECT surfer_stats.user_id,surfer_stats.date,unique_hits,non_unique_hits,earned,sites_surfed,earnings FROM user_visit_logs 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN surfer_stats ON user_visit_logs.user_id = surfer_stats.user_id AND user_visit_logs.date = surfer_stats.date where user_visit_logs.user_id = 23 LIMIT 30 )
```

Simplified, "user_visit_logs" and "surfer_stats" were the 2 tables needed to be joined.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. Just pop them both into a variable:

```
$data = '';

$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT date, stuff* ");
while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
$data.= '<tr><td>--Your Row Data Here--</td></tr>';
}

$query2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT date, other stuff*");
while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)) {
$data .= '<tr><td>--Your Row Data Here--</td></tr>';
}

echo "<table>$data</table>";
```

Instead of using `echo` in your loop, you're just storing the results in `$data`. Then, you're echoing it out after all data has been added to it.

As for your second point, it's not a big deal if fields don't exist. If they're null, you'll just have a column that doesn't have data in it.

Here's an example with fake column names:

```
$data = '';

$query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT date, stuff* ");
while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $data.= "<tr><td>{$record[id]}</td><td>{$record[first_name]}</td><td>{$record[last_name]}</td></tr>";
}

$query2 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT date, other stuff*");
while($record = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)) {
    $data .= "<tr><td>{$record[id]}</td><td>{$record[first_name]}</td><td>{$record[last_name]}</td></tr>";
}

    echo "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th></tr>$data</table>";
```

I have a feeling I may have misunderstood the need. If so, I apologize. If you can elaborate just a bit more I can change my answer :)